# Visual Studio Exception settings ignored C++

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2017, try-catch, assert

I'm testing the assert method in C++ in Visual Studio 2017 and am getting an assertion exception as I would have expected. But after turning off all(!) exception settings I still get an exception thrown before it can be handled by my catch block (see below for an example).

```
try {
    assert(validate(1363821) == false);
    assert(validate(3848238) == true);
    printf("Validation correctly implemented.");
} catch ( exception & e ){
    const string error = e.what();
    printf("Validation failed!");
}
```

So my questions are:

- Am I doing something wrong here?
- Or does the assert method throw some sort of exception which can't be handled by a catch block and will always generate a fatal exception? If so, how can one implement an assert method without creating fatal errors?

My exception settings are not set as is shown below:
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If by `I still get an exception thrown before it can be handled by my catch block` you mean you get a messagebox, thats not visual studio, thats how assert is implemented.

Comment: @tkausl The messagebox is titled "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library" and gives a 'Debug error!' message. Is this not Visual Studio? If not, how can one prevent this messagebox? Or is this behaviour by design that can not be altered?

Comment: Compile in release mode. But your code seems like you're checking whether your code works the way you expect, you should use a testing framework for that purpose.

Comment: You use `assert` if you want your program to terminate ASAP because it just discovered a bug which a programmer needs to handle by fixing the code and releasing a new version. You throw an exception if you want your program to continue doing something (that "something" being your code in the `catch` block, which may not even lead to program termination but make your program continue happily). Those two language features should not be confused with each other.

Answer (score 2):

Assertion failure is not supposed to throw any exceptions. Instead it performs some implementation-specific report actions (such as printing an error message into stderr or showing that dialog) and then calls `std::abort`. So `catch` block and / or exception handling settings in IDE won't do anything in this situation. If you want assertion to throw an exception then you will need to write your own `assert` macro substitution.

If you are looking for some sort verification checking then you better utilize some dedicated framework, such as boost::test. Then you can write simply:

```
 BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(Doc_Parse_Empty)
 {
     BOOST_TEST(validate(1363821) == false);
     BOOST_TEST(validate(3848238) == true);
 }
```

It will also handle success/failure reporting automatically and seamlessly integrates into VS.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I guess that the assert method is actually correct in pointing out that I have a bug and in terminating the application, so that I can't easily bypass it with a try catch block. Is that it?

Comment: Just wondering... I was set on the wrong track I guess because of the Exception setting "Win32 Exceptions > 0xc0000420 Assertion Failed". So apparently this has nothing to do with supressing the Assert method error?!

Comment: @etri I'm afraid `assert` macro exists to deal with invariants checking in debug builds. And any assertion failure is treated as fatal error (that is program execution is not allowed to continue). But I've updated my answer with some alternative.

Comment: @etri Win32 exceptions are not the same thing as `C++ exceptions` and can not be catched with C++ `try..catch` block. Actually some of them are hardware exceptions while some are just how runtime handles fatal errors (assertion failure being one of such errors).

Comment: I disagree with the sentiment that `assert` is only for "debug" builds. I think `assert` is very important in "release" builds to keep wrong code from corrupting data or creating security holes. `assert` can even be enabled or disabled per compilation unit via `NDEBUG`. What you need is a reliable process restarting mechanism.

Comment: @ChristianHackl If there is no `NDEBUG` defined then it is a debug build...

Comment: @VTT: No, `NDEBUG` is a C++ *standard* feature. "Debug" is just a preset name for a set of configuration options in the Visual Studio IDE, which includes not setting the `NDEBUG` macro in all compilation units (in contrast to "Release"). A stronger difference between the two is the C++ runtime used by the linker. But you can change all of this, to some degree.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Not really, it is a common practice to call builds that include through verification (along with all the overhead that it brings) via assertions and/or other means "Debug" builds, and call builds without such verification (that is defining `NDEBUG`) "Release" builds. Besides VS this approach is used in cmake for example.

Comment: @VTT: It's a common convention, but it's just that - a convention. And what I said still stands: (1) `NDEBUG` can be activated per compilation unit, (2) disabling all assertions in production software is a bad idea.